# How do I run a beanshell script on my Mac?

Tags: macos

My Ubuntu-friend told me to testrun a Beanshell script by doing:

```
bsh #filename#
```

and when I told him that I don't know what bsh is nor have it he told me:

```
sudo apt-get install bsh
```

Being on a Mac I instead ran:

```
sudo port install beanshell
```

But still no `bsh` command available. A listing of the package content revealed a jar file named:

```
/opt/local/share/java/bsh.jar
```

but when I try to run that with my script file a complete Window manager written in Java starts up (and does not run the script file btw). Now, clearly I am doing something wrong, I am sure there must be a way of running beanshell scripts on a mac terminal although it does seem more natural for the linux users. What am I doing wrong and what should I do to run that script?

Comment: If you want to know how to do it: `java -cp /opt/local/share/java/bsh.jar bsh.Interpreter`
(apparently I am not allowed to answer) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check that `bsh.jar` is on your CLASSPATH. If it is not, add it by running:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/local/share/java/bsh.jar
```

Then run it like this:

```
java bsh.Interpreter filename
```

See the [manual](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html) for more information.

Comment: yea even nicer. I got totally side tracked by the instructions to just run `bsh filename`...

Comment: You could write a shell script called `bsh` consisting of `java -cp /opt/local/share/java/bsh.jar bsh.Interpreter "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X, someone has created a Beanshell installer.

https://github.com/mcandre/beanshell-mac/blob/master/BeanShell-2.0b4.dmg

Answer (score -1):

Its even easier if you just drop the bsh.jar  into your JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext  directory.   Then you only need to call it with:   **java bsh.Interpreter filename.bsh** without needing to mess with the classpath.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting jars in JAVA_HOME/jre, because if you upgrade the JRE, you have to remember to copy yours jars into the new JRE. (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068961/is-putting-external-jars-in-the-java-home-lib-ext-directory-a-bad-thing)

Comment: In the case of beanshell, its just one jar, so its no problem.  I usually have my shell script copy the jar into place if its missing and so i dont forget.